# Changing font size based on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have:

```
<input type="text" name="changefont" value="16">
```

How do I change a certain node's `font-size` (for example a paragraph) based on `keyup` when user types in the value of the font they want?

So far I thought it would be this, but I guess not:

```
 $('input[name="changefont"]').bind("keyup", function(){
 var fontSize = $(this).val();
 $('p').css('font-size', fontSize);
 });
```

Comment: Check name attribute...

Comment: input[name="font"] should be input[name="changefont"] if I am not mistaken

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to change that part when I posted it to stackoverflow as an example from my code. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the selector typo, you need to add a unit in addition to the inputs value:

```
$('input[name="changefont"]').bind("keyup", function() {
    var fontSize = $(this).val();
    $('p').css('font-size', fontSize + "px");
});
```

I also recommend using `.on()` in place of `.bind()` especially if you're using ver. 1.7+

Comment: Just to mention, it was the adding units part that fixed it. Seems like it does not work without correct units. The typo was fixed on the post. I will also look over .on(), thanks!

Comment: @Naz: Correct, because `font-size: 16` for example is an invalid CSS rule. The value for `font-size` requires a unit unless you use a keyword, e.g. medium.